# Assign a different color to each face using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

It is easy to set the position of each vertex of a mesh using the SetPositionNode. The change in position is nicely shown in the spreadsheet.
The spreadsheet also lists the faces. Is it possible to assign a color depending on the index of the face?
What would be the corresponding input node for the face data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [Store Named Attribute](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/store_named_attribute.html) node and set the domain to *Face*:

[image: A simple geometry nodes setup coloring each face of the input geometry with a random color based on index as a seed]